# Чтение из файла в структуру С++

Tags: c++

задача - составить программу для управления данными. Данные считываются из файла в структуру, из структуры в вектор(для редактирования и так далее). Основная проблема - чтение данных из файла в структуру, никак не могу понять - как это сделать.

```
struct print{
   string marka, format, speed, price;
};
```

Моя структура, данные считываются из текстового файла. как сделать ввод?
Данные в тестовом файле:

```
Canon Panasonic HP
A4 A5 A4
100 10 50
22000 200000 10000
```

Comment: Чтобы понять как читать данные, нужно понять в каком они формате записаны.

Comment: Какой формат текстового файла? Если произвольный то можно сделать такой: marka;format;speed;price. Потом считывать файл построчно и парсить по разделителю

Comment: @Anton а никто не говорил про текстовый, может там бинарник хитрый?

Comment: В вопросе сказано что текстовый

Comment: Данные в формате текста

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как считывать структуру из файла?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642331/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: @Anton если можно пример, было бы замечательно, только начал изучать языки)

Comment: Используй `cin.getline`

Comment: @Anton хм, специально же посмотрел и не увидел.

Comment: @Viktor Не совсем понятно в чем проблема тогда, если там текст.

Comment: @Qwerity Для этого нужен фиксированный размер, если я не ошибаюсь, в данном случае он не фиксированный

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Возможно проблемы и нет, просто я не знаю как это сделать)
Попробовал разные методы, но неполучаетсо(
Людей знающих в круге общения нет, так как я на первом курсе, делаю лабу за 3ий, поэтому пришел сюда

Comment: @Viktor читаете по одному байту (то есть символу), если символ не пробел - добавляете его к строке. Если символ пробел - пропускаете его и следующий символ нужно будет писать в другу строку. Если встретили конец строки - переходить к следующей структуре. Например так.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Сработает для string? Конец строки, если я не ошибаюсь это "\0" - но это же для char?А для string как?

Comment: @Viktor разумеется. Нет проблем написать что-то типа char c = 'G'; string s = "DEF"; s = s + c;

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Спасибо, буду пробовать, если возникнут какие-то вопросы, можно будет обратиться?)

Comment: @Viktor создаете вопрос, прикладываете сразу (!) код и образец данных для чтения. Четко формулируете проблему, с которой столкнулись... :-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Спасибо)) Учту все замечания)